# npm build for Laravel Vite on cPanel Shared Hosting without Local Build

Tags: php, laravel, npm, vite, cpanel

I'm encountering issues deploying my Laravel Vite app on a cPanel shared hosting environment. My npm version is 5.6.0, and I'm constrained to using Node.js v10.0.0 due to the hosting plan limitations (not VPS or dedicated server). Currently, I've been able to run npm run build locally, push the changes to the hosting server, and it works fine.

I'm seeking guidance on how to run npm run build or any alternative method directly on the production server to compile files without having to execute the build process locally. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!